# How to use magnitude and absdiff OpenCV functions to compute distances?

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0

How can I use `magnitude` and `absdiff`? I read the explanation in [the documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#absdiff), but every time it gives an error because I do not understand how exactly should be input arrays and output. Should it be `vector`, `Mat` or `Scalar`? I tried some but I failed, same with `cartToPolar`. Can anyone give me a small snippet of that, since I didn't find any examples in the documentation?

More precisely, I have the vector `vector<Vec4f> lines;` that contains the end point and start point of 30 lines, so I want to use magnitude to find length of each line. I learned how to use `norm` by for loop but I would like to use `magnitude` so I did it like:

```
double x;
length=magnitude(lines[i][2]-lines[i][0],lines[i][3]-lines[i][1],x)
```

but it doesn't work. I tried to define x as 1 array vector, but I couldn't.

Comment: What's the problem? Can you provide the code you've trouble with?

Comment: @miki I edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already got how to use `norm` to compute the distance:

```
Point2f a = ...
Point2f b = ..
double length = norm(a - b); // NORM_L2, NORM_L1
```

You can also work on all points at once. You first need to convert the coordinates from vector to matrix form, then it's just simple math:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main() 
{
    vector<Vec4f> lines{ { 1, 2, 4, 6 }, { 5, 7, 1, 3 }, { 11, 12, 12, 11 } };

    Mat1f coordinates = Mat4f(lines).reshape(1);
    Mat1f diff_x = coordinates.col(0) - coordinates.col(2);
    Mat1f diff_y = coordinates.col(1) - coordinates.col(3);

    cout << "coordinates: \n" << coordinates << "\n\n";
    cout << "diff_x: \n" << diff_x << "\n\n";
    cout << "diff_y: \n" << diff_y << "\n\n";
    cout << endl;

    // sqrt((x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 - y1)^2)
    Mat1f euclidean_distance;
    magnitude(diff_x, diff_y, euclidean_distance);

    cout << "euclidean_distance: \n" << euclidean_distance << "\n\n";

    // abs(x2 - x1) + abs(y2 - y1)
    Mat1f manhattan_distance = abs(diff_x) + abs(diff_y);

    cout << "manhattan_distance: \n" << manhattan_distance << "\n\n";

    // Another way to compute L1 distance, with absdiff
    // abs(x2 - x1) + abs(y2 - y1)
    Mat1f points1 = coordinates(Range::all(), Range(0, 2));
    Mat1f points2 = coordinates(Range::all(), Range(2, 4));
    Mat1f other_manhattan_distance;
    absdiff(points1, points2, other_manhattan_distance);
    other_manhattan_distance = other_manhattan_distance.col(0) + other_manhattan_distance.col(1);

    cout << "other_manhattan_distance: \n" << other_manhattan_distance << "\n\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank u very much for ur very clear and helpful example and also for editing my question